# Round up half of the hour in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, hour

`round()` function in pandas rounds down the time 07:30 to 07:00 But I want to round up any time which passes the 30 minutes (inclusive).

Eg.

```
07:15 to 07:00
05:25 to 05:00
22:30 to 23:00
18:45 to 19:00
```

How to achieve this for a column of a dataframe using pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### timestamps

You need to use [`dt.round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.round.html). This is however a bit as the previous/next hour behavior depends on the hour itself. You can force it by adding or subtracting a small amount of time (here 1ns):

```
s = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['1/2/2021 3:45', '25/4/2021 12:30', 
                              '25/4/2021 13:30', '12/4/2022 23:45']))

# xx:30 -> rounding depending on the hour parity (default)
s.dt.round(freq='1h')

0   2021-01-02 04:00:00
1   2021-04-25 12:00:00    <- -30min
2   2021-04-25 14:00:00    <- +30min
3   2022-12-05 00:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]


# 00:30 -> 00:00 (force down)
s.sub(pd.Timedelta('1ns')).dt.round(freq='1h')

0   2021-01-02 04:00:00
1   2021-04-25 12:00:00
2   2021-04-25 13:00:00
3   2022-12-05 00:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]


# 00:30 -> 01:00 (force up)
s.add(pd.Timedelta('1ns')).dt.round(freq='1h')

0   2021-01-02 04:00:00
1   2021-04-25 12:00:00
2   2021-04-25 13:00:00
3   2022-12-05 00:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

##### floats

IIUC, you can use [`divmod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.divmod.html) (or [`numpy.modf`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.modf.html)) to get the integer and decimal part, then perform simple boolean arithmetic:

```
s = pd.Series([7.15, 5.25, 22.30, 18.45])

s2, r = s.divmod(1)  # or np.modf(s)

s2[r.ge(0.3)] += 1

s2 = s2.astype(int)
```

Alternative: using [`mod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mod.html) and boolean to int equivalence:

```
s2 = s.astype(int)+s.mod(1).ge(0.3)
```

output:

```
0     7
1     5
2    23
3    19
dtype: int64
```

*Note on precision. It is not always easy to compare floats due to floating point arithmetics. For instance using `gt` would fail on the 22.30 here. To ensure precision round to 2 digits first.*

```
s.mod(1).round(2).ge(0.3)
```

or use integers:

```
s.mod(1).mul(100).astype(int).ge(30)
```

Comment: One could also try `np.ceil` e.g . df - 0.2999 df = df.apply(np.ceil).astype(int).

Comment: @KarelZe yes, nice alternative, but use the vectorial `ceil`: `np.ceil(s.sub(0.299)).astype(int)` ;)

Comment: Can I apply this to a column that has data type of timestamp?

Comment: @mozway  Yes, this even better :)

Comment: @FazN can you provide your real example (`df.to_dict()`)? I would probably use a different approach with timestamps

Comment: @FazN I provided an example with timestamps

Comment: I added a few more example as the `round` behaviour is tricky (but justified!)

Answer (score 1):

Here a version that works with timestamps:

```
#dummy data:
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':pd.to_datetime([np.random.randint(0,10**8) for a in range(10)], unit='s')})


def custom_round(df, col, out):
    if df[col].minute >= 30:
        df[out] = df[col].ceil('H')
    else:
        df[out] = df[col].floor('H')
    return df


df.apply(lambda x: custom_round(x, 'time', 'new_time'), axis=1)
```

#edit:

using numpy:

```
def custom_round(df, col, out):
    df[out] = np.where(
        (
            df['time'].dt.minute>=30), 
            df[col].dt.ceil('H'), 
            df[col].dt.floor('H')
    )
    return df
df = custom_round(df, 'time', 'new_time')
```

Comment: It iterates each element by element. I just want to apply the function to all the elements of a column at once